# Gradually changing opacity with JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I have this element:

```
<div id="newDimention">
  <div class="newDimention">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change its opacity with javascript:

```
let newDimention=document.getElementById('newDimention');
```

```
setTimeout(()=>{
 setDimention();
  newDimention.innerText="You've uncovered the third dimension."
   newDimention.style.color="purple";
    newDimention.style.fontSize='30px';
    newDimention.style.marginTop='30px';
    newDimention.style.opacity="0";
    })



const setDimention = () => {
for (var i = 0,b=14; i <= 500; i++) {
 setTimeout(()=>{
//document.getElementById("newDimention").style.opacity=String(Math.round(i/50)/10);
   newDimention.style.opacity=String(Math.round(i/50)/10);
 },i*b)
}
}
```

I tried without converting to a string, tried accessing by the class, id. Devtools clearly show that `String(Math.round(i/50)/10)` gradually increases each time as it should be. But `newDimention.style.opacity` remains `'0'` each time.

Then once `String(Math.round(i/50)/10)==='1'`, `newDimention.style.opacity` changes to `'1'` instantly. So it remains `'0'` for some reason until `i===500`, then suddenly changes to `'1'`. I don't have any other functions manipulating this element. And if I remove the line `newDimention.style.opacity=String(Math.round(i/50)/10);` the opacity stays at `'0'`, so this line is supposed to change the opacity of this element.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I realized that I used `var` instead of `let` in the `for loop`, so when the functions got fired eventually after `setTimeout`, they used `i===500`, the latest value. Changing it to `let` fixed it:

```
const setDimention = () => {
for (let i = 0,b=14; i <= 500; i++) {
 setTimeout(()=>{
//document.getElementById("newDimention").style.opacity=String(Math.round(i/50)/10);
   newDimention.style.opacity=String(Math.round(i/50)/10);
 },i*b)
}
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let:

"`let` allows you to declare variables that are limited to a scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used, unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope".